# Count likes on posts per blog

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm sure the answer to this is trivial but I've been at it for a long time now and can't find the right combination.

I have 3 tables, **Blogs**, **Posts** and **Likes**. I would like to list the **Posts** with the most **Likes** per **Blog**.

Right now to count the likes per post I'm grouping the query like this (ending up with multiple posts from the same blog):

```
select
  posts.*,
  count(*) as c
from posts
inner join likes
  on posts.id = likes.post_id
group by posts.id
```

The relations between the tables are:

```
Blog: id, name
Post: id, name, content, blog_id
Like: id, post_id
```

Comment: please post the columns that yours tables have and the association between the tables. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to list the Posts with the most Likes per Blog.

Assuming that the `posts` table contains a `blog_id`, I think this would satisfy your needs:

```
SELECT p.id AS post_id, p.blog_id, COUNT(1) AS like_count
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN likes l ON (p.id = l.post_id)
GROUP BY p.id, p.blog_id
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

you didn't specify how many of the top posts per blog you needed, so this will return all of them, in order of the most likes, regardless of which blog the post comes from.

If you *only* want the top post per blog, then it's considerably more complicated in MySQL:

```
SELECT v.post_id, v.blog_id, v.like_count 
FROM (
    SELECT p.id AS post_id, p.blog_id, COUNT(1) AS like_count
    FROM posts p
    INNER JOIN likes l ON (p.id = l.post_id)
    GROUP BY p.id, p.blog_id
) v
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(t.like_count) AS like_count, t.blog_id
    FROM (
        SELECT p.id AS post_id, p.blog_id, COUNT(1) AS like_count
        FROM posts p
        INNER JOIN likes l ON (p.id = l.post_id)
        GROUP BY p.id, p.blog_id
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.blog_id
) max_post ON (max_post.like_count = v.like_count AND max_post.blog_id = v.blog_id);
```

You can see the fiddle for this, [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b278/14/0).

Caveat - if two posts for the same blog share the maximum like count for that blog then they will *both* appear in the results.

Comment: Sorry, only the top one yes. I'm getting the error message "Unknown column 'v.id' in 'field list'" with this code though. I'll try to figure out what's missing here too.

Comment: After changing the outer SELECT list to only "*", ordering the inner SELECT to "ORDER BY like_count DESC" and changing the outer grouping to "GROUP BY blog_id" I seem to have reached my goal.Any idea why the aliasing to v wouldn't work in your query and would proposed changes work? (not updated in my question, as I think you're on to the solution and I'd like to reward that).

Comment: In my original, I was referring to `v.id` instead of `v.post_id` - once that was corrected I realised it still doesn't _quite_ meet your needs. I'm more of an Oracle man and it's harder to do what you need in MySQL it seems! See what you think of the above, you can test it on SQLFiddle, linked at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following query gets the count of likes for posts on a blog:

```
select p.blog_id, count(*) as numlikes
from posts p inner join
     likes l
     on p.id = l.post_id
group by p.blog_id;
```

To get the maximum . . . Well, this isn't so much fun in MySQL for an aggregation query.  Here is one method that uses `substring_index()`/`group_concat()`

```
select p.blog_id, max(numlikes) as maxnumlikes,
       substring_index(group_concat(p.id order by numlikes desc), ',', 1
                      ) as MostLikedPostId
from (select p.blog_id, p.id, count(*) as numlikes,
      from posts p inner join
           likes l
           on p.id = l.post_id
      group by p.blog_id, p.id
     ) pb;
```

If you want more information about the post, then you can add an additional join to get the post information.